# VBA for saving worksheet with dynamic date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save an excel workbook at the end of the macro with a dynamic date in the file name.  I want the name to contain the previous month.  For instance, if the macro is run on 8/9/2013 I want the file to save with 7/2013 specified.  This is what I have and it works great if I use the current month.  But, if I ran this on 8/9/2013 I would want the file to save as "Monthly Report 2013-07".

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\FULL PATH\Monthly Report " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm") & ".xls"

End Sub
```

I've also used something like this previously, but couldn't get this to subtract a month either:

```
wbNam = "Monthly Report_"
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= wbNam & dt
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dt = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now), "yyyy_mm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this function

```
Public Function PreviousMonth(ByVal d As Date) As Date
PreviousMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) - 1, Day(d))
End Function
```

`DateSerial` is smart enough to support zero or negative month numbers.
In other words PreviousMonth(#1/1/2000#) is December 1st 1999.

Comment: I might try to get this down as well,I am sure it works, it is just my ignorance that I can't figure it out... Seems like it could be useful going forward, but I couldn't get it to work right away, so I went with the other method.  Thanks though!